# Query top 2 salaries in each department

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Query:

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by b.[Dept Name] order by a.salary) as row_rank
from dbo.d as a
inner join dbo.e as b on a.[Dept id] = b.[Dept id]
row_rank < 3
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
> Incorrect syntax near 'row_rank'.

I wish to query the following columns:

- table1: Name, Salary, Dept_id
- table 2: Dept_id, Dept_Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference a calculated column directly in the `where` clause. Use a CTE or sub-query.

```
with cte as (
    select a.Name, a.salary a.[Dept id], b.Dept_Name
        , row_number() over (partition by b.[Dept Name] order by a.salary) as row_rank
    from dbo.d as a
    inner join dbo.e as b on a.[Dept id] = b.[Dept id]
)
select *
from cte
where row_rank < 3;
```

You don't need [dept id] from both tables as they are the same. Also its advised to alias your tables with a meaningful alias, not just a, b etc